# HTML command-line-like text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a text box that executes custom commands with custom syntax, it is for teaching children how to program.

A simple example is that if the user wrote a `$` sign the program alerts by a message (you are now writing a variable name), on the same text box if he added `!=` the alert says not equal, and so on.

Right now I'm doing it using jQuery `KeyUp` event, by running several regex tests and on each test the alert box alerts.

I want to ask if there is a better approach to do this?

Comment: I'd write a simple lexer/parser for your teaching language, instead of using regex patterns.

Comment: You'd def. to look into something more advanced, parser-wise. Regex is going to be a mess when you want to figure out, for instance, whether the `!=` is inside a string or not, taking into consideration quotes, double quotes, escaped quotes, and whatnot. And that's just one of the complications.

Comment: I've written basic language parsers by applying the interpreter pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern. This will give you much better accuracy than regex.

Answer (score 0):

For a dead simple solution, Why not just use the node.js REPL or the browser console ?

There are many places where this is done in a full blown teaching sites however.
check out this one, for example for instance:
 [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/levels/1/challenges/1)